# Método Split - Separar em 3 partes

Tags: java

Tenho uma instrução para separar duas palavras de uma string e colocar em um array. Esta instrução está funcionando muito bem. Segue abaixo:

```
public static List<String> converterCamelCase(String original) {

        String[] arraySplit = original.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"); 
}
```

Exemplo: "nomeComposto", resultado será "nome" (0) e Composto (1).

Só que agora preciso ajustar essa instrução para separar em 3 partes - Exemplo:
NomeCPFContribuinte, resultado "Nome"(0) CPF(1) Contribuinte(2)

Como posso fazer isso?

Eu quero fazer com que essa mesma instrução separe duas ou três palavras. No momento eu só consigo separar em ATÉ 2 partes. Exemplo de palavras: nome - “nome”, nomeComposto - “nome”, “Composto”, numeroCPF - “numero”, “CPF”.

No caso de uma string com números, vai acontecer do método receber essa formatação de string, exemplo: recupera10Primeiros - “recupera”, “10”, “Primeiros”.

Será que é possível fazer isso em uma mesma instrução?

Comment: Importante você definir bem quais são as suas necessidades - separar as três letras "CPF" ali no meio não é difícil - o problema é se você trocar sua `String` para outras letras, ou usar números, ou mudar sua quantidade. Qual é a sua intenção?

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/207064/edit) e inclua mais informações na sua pergunta, ao invés de responder aqui nos comentários... :)

Comment: Se possível, dê mais exemplos de uso (com `Strings` diferentes) - aproveite para fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), vale uma medalha!

Comment: com esse CPF tudo em maiúsculas complica um pouco, dei um replace nele e ficou assim      https://ideone.com/mPgYh0

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo o problema ai é que se aparecer outras siglas(RG, IR, PIS, etc), teria que tratar todas na mão, ai é trabalheira demais.

Comment: é verdade por isso não coloquei como resposta :)

Comment: Obrigada Daniel e Leo. Vou continuar tentando fazer com expressão regular.

Comment: Acho que eu entendi o que você quer - você gostaria que o programa reconhecesse as palavras para separá-las. Você só consegue isso com o uso de um dicionário. Usando [tag:regex], ele precisa se apoiar em alguma regra bem determinada para fazer separações, por exemplo por vírgula, espaço, hífen, etc. Outra maneira, é deixar apenas **uma** maiúscula por palavra ex.: `NomeCpfContribuinte` não seria difícil separar.

Comment: Oi Daniel, como eu sou iniciante em java e não sei usar as expressões regulares com desenvoltura, fiz exatamente isso, deixei apenas uma maiúscula por palavra (NomeCpfContribuinte). Mas quero estudar mais sobre expressões regulares. Muito obrigada pelo retorno.